# How to fit an image in Bootstrap carousel slider if image is not large?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a carousel slider in my front page. My problem is my image width doesn't fit in my window.

Here is the printscreen of my sample slider:

[image: How to set the image in 100%?]

I already set the image to 100% but when sliding the image goes back to it's original size then the next image will fit to the page.

I have this codes:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="float: none !important;">
                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <a href="http://www.kamakurashirts.net/shop/pages/vintageivyshirts2014.aspx">
                                <img src="./images/banner0.png" title="This is banner 1" class="img-responsive slider_image_item" />
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            <a href="http://www.kamakurashirts.net/shop/c/c102001">
                                <img src="./images/banner1.png" title="This is banner 2" class="img-responsive slider_image_item" />
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            <a href="http://www.kamakurashirts.net/shop/e/eNEW/">
                                <img src="./images/banner2.png" title="This is banner 3" class="img-responsive slider_image_item" />
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="item">
                            <a href="http://www.kamakurashirts.net/shop/pages/find_your_size.aspx">
                                <img src="./images/banner3.png" title="This is banner 4" class="img-responsive slider_image_item" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <a id="left-slide" class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
                    <a id="right-slide" class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>

            </div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

And this CSS:

```
.slider_image_item { 
    width: 100% !important; 
    max-width: 1400px !important;
}
```

What should I need do to to set my image into 100% in my page. The original size of the image is in the picture I included.

Comment: Remove the max-width. If you want the image to be 100% of the viewport, provided that there is no padding on the .item, then that's all you need. And you don't need !important.

Comment: Ok same result after removing the max-width :( it fit but before scrolling to next slide it goes back to it's original slide then the next slide will fit. :(

Comment: And the width of your .item is? No way of knowing unless all the css is provided for this carousel. Compare your css with this: http://jsfiddle.net/heyallanmoreno/7TdVu/4/